# Ubuntu terminal, How do I "tab" (autocomplete) a filename window-cmd-style(cycle options)?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bash, terminal

Basically i want to change ubuntu terminal functionally, so that i can cycle thru all the options when i tab(on the cmd line row) and not list the options as it is per default?

Im using bash, ubuntu 9.04. I see some possibilities in ".bashrc",  but there must be someone out there who already solved this problem?

Comment: you do know that if press Tab twice you got a list of all possible completion, don't you?

Comment: @vava: You're describing bash's possible-completions command, which is usually the default behavior.  The question is how to replace this behavior with the behavior provided by bash's menu-complete command.

Comment: @las3rjock, I know, that's why I left a comment, not an answer. It is just possible that OP doesn't know about that feature since it is way better than cycling mode.

Comment: @vava: The OP describes the possible-completions behavior and states that he wants to replace it with the menu-complete behavior.

Comment: @vava i do know how the terminal works, and i want to change this much annoying behavior.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the comments on [this page](http://lwn.net/Articles/182740/), putting

```
bind '"\t":menu-complete'
```

in your `.bashrc` should enable cyclic tab completion.

See [section 8.4.6](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Commands-For-Completion) of the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, very nice find! - Just love the comment on that page "It has taken me years to find out that bash supports cyclic tab completion"- hah, superuser wins!

Comment: Thanks! Once this is implemented, is there an override key combination to use the old way momentarily? Shift+TAB, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Something that is a life-saver for me is to have bash cycle through the possibilities instead of showing a dumb list.

As bash is using `readline` for its auto-completion, add the following lines to `~/.inputrc`

*Once you're satisfied and have thoroughly tested below solution for a few days/weeks, **cut and paste** (don't copy!) the same settings from `~/.inputrc` to `/etc/inputrc` which contains the system-wide settings, making this available to all users on your system (including guest).*

#### The codez:

```
# mappings to have up and down arrow searching through history:
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
# mappings to have left and right arrow go left and right: 
"\e[C": forward-char
"\e[D": backward-char

# mapping to have [Tab] and [Shift]+[Tab] to cycle through all the possible completions:
"\t": menu-complete
"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward
```

then `exit` your terminal (or remote terminal like putty) and open it again...

#### Examples:

1. When you have 3 files: `file1`, `file2` and `file3` and you type:

   ```
   e fTabTabTab
   ```

   it'll cycle through:

   ```
   e file1
   e file2
   e file3
   ```

   and when you want to go back, just hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
2. When you type:

   ```
   very-complicated-command with lots of command line parameters
   ```

   and next time you need the same command, you just type:

   ```
   very↑
   ```

   and it'll type for you:

   ```
   very-complicated-command with lots of command line parameters
   ```

### This will save you a ton of time in bash!  ;-)

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/607903/344926)